Could you suffocate someone to death with a big enough standing wave?
I'm not great with physics, so I could really use some help here.
My understanding of waves in terms of air pressure is that you have regions of rarefactions (lower air pressure) and condensations (higher air pressure). The size of these areas correspond to frequency, and the intensity of the corresponding shift in pressure corresponds to amplitude.
My understanding of a standing wave is like the above, but the areas are not moving in space; the condensations and rarefactions stand still; the phase doesn't change, is my assumption about how this works.
So, my question is, given the following conditions:

A standing sonic wave...
With a wavelength of roughly 1-2 metres...
And an amplitude sufficient to rarify air pressure to the point where the oxygen available is not sufficient for human life...
And a non-moving human target...

Could someone be suffocated to death with such a wave?

Some great answers; just to get more visibility on a question I asked in the comments; if this isn't how standing waves work, then why is it in demonstrations involving pipes with holes, flammable gases and a sound wave, certain waves cause certain flames to go out entirely, in a static location along the pipe?

With a big enough standing wave you could pulverize their body into mush.  FWIW, there is ultimately only one true cause of death: lack of oxygen to the brain - or lack of brain, I suppose.  Does that count as suffocation?  ;)

Beside that, even if some mysterious circumstance would make possible to significantly decrease the average air pressure, the resulting sound would be unlikely survivable.

That's not how a standing wave works.
From Wikipedia:

In physics, a standing wave, also known as a stationary wave, is a wave that oscillates in time but whose peak amplitude profile does not move in space.

It's only peaks and nodes to not change position, but the amplitude still changes. Look at this animation of a standing wave on a disc:

you can see that peaks and nodes are always in the same place, but the amplitude still changes.
So you cannot create permanent vacuum with a standing wave.
That said, a sound wave with the low pressure at 0 bar will kill not because of asphyxia but because a pressure change from 2 to 0 bar will cause massive damage to an organism experiencing it. It would correspond to a sound at 191 dB (source)

Interesting, this is super useful, thank you.
I've seen demonstrations online, with the pipes full of some flammable gas and a sound wave, and holes drilled at intervals; they seem to be able to produce the static rarefactions I mentioned, as certain frequencies cause certain holes to produce less/no flame (and corresponding larger flames) at static points, for as long as the wave is maintained. How is this working?

@ConnieMnemonic - per Instructables - it doesn't have to do with the pressure (directly, at least), but rather with gas flow.   The pressure is constant averaged over time, but because at the wave crests/troughs it is oscillating relative to the outside pressure, the flow (out the hole) is reduced.  (The flow is proportional to the square root of the difference in pressures, so even though the "high" pressure at the crests is greater than at the nodes, it doesn't increase as much as the reduction decreases it.)

@jdunlop Interesting! Still not sure I understand fully; sounds like a reason for me to do some more reading! Thanks again :)


A wavelength of sound in air of 1 to 2 meters means a frequency of 343 to 686 Hz, which is perfectly audible. (From F above middle C to the F one octave higher.)

Let's say that that "to rarify air pressure to the point where the oxygen available is not sufficient for human life" means 0.5 atmospheres; note that the usual definition of the death zone is 0.35 atmospheres, but that's for trained athletes.
0.5 atm is about 500 millibar, or 50,000 Pa. Compared to the reference level of 20 μPa, a sound wave which produces a sound pressure of 500 mbar is at
$$20\log_{10}\frac{50,000,000,000}{20} = 188\,\text{dB}_\text{peak}$$
The person is dead from sound pressure alone, we don't have to even consider the effect of diminished oxygen level.

Oh, and the oxygen level won't be dimished at all on the average. Yes, 343 to 686 times per second air pressure will go down to 0.5 atm. But immediately after that, also 343 to 686 times per second, it will go up to 1.5 atm; so that on the average it will remain at 1 atm. Sound is a vibration; the pressure goes down and up around the mean.



L. Dutch nailed it, but since you mentioned that you're still having trouble visualizing it, I'll refer you to this brilliant article from Penn State. In particular, this animation is the absolute best I could find to illustrate a standing pressure wave in a gas:

Animation courtesy of Dr. Dan Russell, Grad. Prog. Acoustics, Penn State.
In particular, notice the following:

There is no place in the wave where the pressure is statically low. There are, however, places where the pressure remains constant at some middle-of-the-road value. We call these pressure nodes.
At the pressure nodes, the displacement (and therefore velocity also) of the gas particles is at an anti-node, meaning that it oscillates more than at any other location.

This means that in a standing pressure wave, you can either be at a location where the pressure oscillates but the particles are not moving (on average), or a location where the pressure is constant but the velocity is oscillating.
If you're interested in killing someone with a wave, suffocation is probably not the approach. However, a pressure wave of sufficiently high amplitude (standing or not) will kill a person with sheer trauma. So you have options!

These animations are super useful, thanks! I'm actually more confused though about why the flames in a Ruben's Tube are lower at the antinodes; if the pressure is still the same on average, why do the flames dwindle? Wikipedia is unclear on the details here.

Wow, you sent me much further down a rabbit hole than I expected. Thanks! You're right, there are a lot of super hand-wavy explanations out there that don't actually get at the real reason. I found one video though that actually did a deep dive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbPgy4sHYTw.
Turns out the explanation of the flame heights is more subtle than I would have thought!

Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. So it seems that additional pressure essentially has "diminishing returns"; the converse being that less pressure has far more impact. So while the average pressure is the same, the average flow is reduced because the trough of the wave contributes more to the flow rate than the crest. How curious! Thank you!
